# Front-end developer in a .NET world - What do I need to know?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frontend

When working on the front-end of a .NET application what are the basic prerequisites? What do I need to know in order to survive, assuming I already have knowledge of HTML/CSS/JavaScript plus a general awareness of the MVC pattern and how it works. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, you need to know very little. The UI work is all about HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

The bonus-features that will help you to make good designs are:

1) Master Pages (this is a template that can be applied to many pages, so you just populate it with the content areas)

2) Partial Views (you can create a "bit" of a web page, which the server will stitch into a single html page AND that you can load using an AJAX call)

Answer (score 1):

I would add localization by using resourcefiles.

You might also get involved into some simple formating like displaying a currency value.

If you know jquery well you might be able to impress people with little effort.

Answer (score 1):

i think nothing else only JavaScript , css , HTML. but you will must have the knowledge of server side technologies architecture, like how the data should be passed across the layers, 
business logic layer , data access layer and database layer.

When front end engineer writing html , javascript , css they are looking to back end developer , they must know about how the back end developer will handle this or they will collaborate with them.